# Apache Mod Rewrite Rule?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a javascript script that is loaded into a webpage. Part of that script builds some URLs and the server I have it on is not able to properly build the URLs (URLs are another server/domain) so I need to add a mod rewrite to the URL. I have working mod rewrites with [P] proxy flag that work for javascript files. But this is a HTTP Post endpoint. I'm not sure if I'm writing it wrong or how to start with debugging? Its running on a websphere server that has httpd.conf file that adds them in. I'm guessing its some sort of apache mode plugin or functionality built in.

```
RewriteRule ^/endpoint/to/call https://www.anotherfake.com/endpoint/to/call [P]
```

Without a rule the page tries to call POST: https://www.myfake.com/endpoint/to/call but I want it to call POST: https://www.anotherfake.com/endpoint/to/call

When I tried the rule above it has 500 and 504 errors. If I remove the proxy [P] option it tries to do redirect to the correct URL runs into CORS errors. I believe the standard redirect or mod redirect without proxy cannot handle POST?